# How to handle calendar appointments in MariaDB

Tags: php, sql, database-design, mariadb

I am using a database (MariaDB) to support a PHP-driven school class calendar. I have a table, *Class*, which stores, amongst other things, the start time and duration of the class. And I have another table, *Teacher*, which stores teacher information. Only one teacher will ever be assigned to a class, and classes always begin on the hour.

I want to ensure that no new class is booked with a particular teacher whilst s/he is in the middle of another class. If classes were just one hour long, I would simply enforce a UNIQUE constraint on *Teacher* and *Class*, but since classes may be more than one hour long, I am not sure how to approach this.

I could, of course, perform a check in the PHP before the INSERT, but I would have thought it better practice to design the database to make it impossible to have any one teacher's classes overlapping. I have looked at SQL procedures, but I am not familiar with their use, and I have not found an example that so much as approaches the kind of check that I need to perform here.

*Can anyone suggest how this problem might best be approached?*

Answer (score 0):

Use time slots (15 min) to mark both, teachers and classes as busy.

```
-- Teacher TCH exists.
--
teacher {TCH}
     PK {TCH}
```

```
-- Class CLS exists.
--
class {CLS}
   PK {CLS}
```

```
-- Time slot number SLT, starting at STA is 15 min long.
--
tslot {SLT, STA}
   PK {SLT}


-- data sample
  (SLT, STA)
---------------
  (1, '00:00')
, (2, '00:15')
, (3, '00:30')
, (4, '00:45')
, (5, '01:00')
-- ...
, (95, '23:30')
, (96, '23:45')

-- This is a "static" table, once populated make it read-only.
```

From the application level, populate all slots in this table
based on *teacher, class, start time, and end time for a given date*.
Make sure it is done within a transaction, so an error rolls everything back.

```
-- On date DTE, teacher TCH is busy with class CLS
-- during time slot number SLT.
--
busy {DTE, SLT, TCH, CLS}
  PK {DTE, SLT, TCH}
  AK {DTE, SLT, CLS}

FK1 {SLT} REFERENCES tslot   {SLT}
FK2 {TCH} REFERENCES teacher {TCH}
FK3 {CLS} REFERENCES class   {CLS}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

---

This far from perfect, it can be messed-up by random updates, say changing teacher in a slot in the middle of the class. Hence the application should enforce rules to prevent weird entries.